# Função em javascript retorna undefined ao invés de valor boolean

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou tentando fazer com que a minha função retorne de true ou false, mas sempre me retorna undefined.
Acredito que a minha lógica esteja certa.

```
onChangeCategoria(categoria: any, itemchecked) {

    this.itemcheckado = itemchecked;

    if (!categoria.selecionado) {
      this.services.confirmation.confirm({
        message: `A categoria ${categoria.nome} ainda
        não foi configurada para essa solicitação! Deseja configurar?`,
        accept: () => {
          const { id, nome, quantidadeDePessoas } = categoria;
          this.categoriaSelecionada = {
            id,
            nome,
            quantidadeDePessoas,
            paginaAtual: 1
          };
          categoria.selecionado = true;
          this.adicionarCategoria();
          this.itemcheckado.target.checked = true;
    }, reject: () => {
      categoria.selecionado = categoria.selecionado;
      this.itemcheckado.target.checked = false;
    }
  })} else {
    this.itemcheckado.target.checked  = this.confirmarRemocaoCategoria(categoria);
    categoria.selecionado = false;
  }
}

  confirmarRemocaoCategoria(categoria: any) {
    this.services.confirmation.confirm({
      message: `Deseja realmente remover a categoria ${categoria.nome}?`,
      accept: () => {
        if (this.novaSolicitacao()) {
          this.removerCategoriaSelecionada(categoria);
        } else {
          this.removerCategoria(categoria);
        }
        return false;
      },
      reject: () => true
    });
  }
```

Comment: Qual função seria??

Comment: A minha onChangeCategoria, chama a Confirmar Remoção, que deveria me retornar true ou false.
mas retorna undefined

Comment: Não vi nenhum return nessa função

Comment: Pois é, eu to tentando até agora descobrir se é a primeira ou a segunda que retorna undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paulo, acontece que sua função retorna um boolean conforme o consumo de um serviço, sendo assim ela fica com um comportamento assíncrono, você teria que trabalhar com async/await ou refatorar o código de alguma forma, por exemplo, enviando o this.itemcheckado.target como parâmetro para a função confirmarRemocaoCategoria.

Comment: faz sentindo, no meu caso não teria como passar como parametro.
Então vou ter que trablhar com async/await.